# Set the "internet connection check page" Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, networking, internet-connection

Every now and then my Windows 10 machine decides it's not connected to the internet and I need to sign in to the wifi again (why it does that is a side-quest that I'm taking up with Enterprise support).

When this happens it says in various different locations and various different ways to use a browser to sign into my local wifi.  A specific example of this message is from outlook where it says "CHECK YOUR CONNECTION To get new email use your browser to sing in to ORBI" - ORBI is the name of my wifi.

When I click on the link or the button it opens Firefox (default browser, all good) and navigates to `www.msn.com` and that's BAD.

I don't like MSN.
There are lots of useful websites that I could use instead, which are equally reliable. (e.g StackExchange).

How do I set the page that it will use to confirm it has internet connection?

**Edit:** a bit more detail (thanks for the questions):

It's not a Firefox setting. I switched default browser to Chrome which is rather more controlled by my work and got the same result.

ORBI is my home network. This doesn't happen at work.

When I click on the link the browser initially goes to
`www.msftconnecttest.com/redirect`

It gets a 302 redirect to
`http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=219472&clcid=0x409`

Which results in a redirect to
https://www.msn.com/?ocid=wispr&pc=u477

So I guess it's down to whether I can change that initial `www.msftconnecttest.com` URL

**Edit** more detail.

I did a registry search for `msftconnecttest` and found a set of entries at `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc\Parameters\Internet` that reference it.

I found a couple of web pages that discuss editing it.
https://networkproguide.com/fix-connect-attempts-to-www-msftconnecttest-com-windows-server-2016/
(Windows server 2016)

(Vista, not Windows 10)
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//ms697388(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

I thought it was worth a bash, so I've edited `ActiveWebProbeHost` and `ActiveWebProbeHostV6` to point to a site under my control that will respond on port 80 (with a redirect to https, but whatever).

That's made no difference, I still end up on MSN.

Thanks.

Comment: I would wonder if this is possible. MSN would likely be specific to Outlook (or perhaps Edge). Personally, I can't recall  ever being redirected to MSN through a non-Microsoft product. Have you perhaps looked into the settings for any "default" page for Firefox?

Comment: Could you add to your post an example of such a URL? Does this happen at work and ORBI is your work router?